# how to exit from currentrunloop

Tags: iphone

I used NSRunloop in my application. While going from my current controller i need to exit from the run loop also. How can i exit from current run loop .

Runloop is implemented as follows.

```
while(!completed) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2.0]];//[NSDate distantFuture]
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've got in one of my projects. Seems to be working....

```
do {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
} while (!finished);
```

Answer (score 0):

To kill the run loop within the loop, you have to use [CoreFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html):

```
CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
```

Better, as stated in the manual of `-runMode:beforeDate:`

> … it returns after either the first input source is processed or *limitDate* is reached …

So you could install an input source ([CFRunLoopSource](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopSourceRef/Reference/reference.html)) to the run loop, and fire it when you're done.